# "Error parsing XML: junk after document element"

Tags: android

I get this error message while trying to create custom button, i have already tried most of the answers similar to my question but cant get it working yet. Any help much appreciated. Also, as this is my first time posting here, forgive me if anything wrong with the rules.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 <Selector
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <item android:drawable="@drawable/touchlighter" android:state_pressed="true"/>
           <item android:drawable="@drawable/touch"/>
 </Selector>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're typing `<Selector ...` where the attributes of the `<RelativeLayout>` should go.

I think the right XML should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Selector>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/touchlighter" android:state_pressed="true"/>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/touch"/>
    </Selector>
</RelativeLayout>
```